# Allow users to enter items to custom list but not view the list

Tags: 2013

This question may have been asked in the past, but not sure if it was in context of SP 2013 or SP online. We have a need for users to be able to add items to a custom list using a form (list form), but not being able to view the list itself. Only a select group of staff should be able to view the list.

Comment: What type of solution is it?  Farm or App?

Comment: It is supposed to be an App solution.

Answer (score 3):

You won't have such functionality out-of-box but i can suggest you something that you may find helpful

follow this
List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Item Level permissions.

Change read and edit access to only the ones created by the user.

So now the users will able to see or edit their own items only and not those items created by other users

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

- Give `Read` and `Edit` permission to user, so then user will able to
  see only items inserted by him.
- Create custom form on webpart to insert data into list.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra advices:

1- you can hide list from designer in list settings
2- you can edit masterpage and check if requsted URL is list url redirect to another page.